# Ember - Having problems rerendering template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Im having problems with letting hbs know that a property has changed.
Ive tried "propertyDidchange" etc. Nothing seems to be working.

I've a form counter

```
personFormCount: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

And form hbs

```
{{#each personFormCount}}
      <br>Form ID: {{id}}
      <button type="submit" {{action 'getID' id}}>ID</button> // sends ID
      {{view 'person'}}
{{/each}}
```

JS

```
getID: function(id){
          var index = id - 1;
          this.get('personFormCount').splice(index, 1);
          this.notifyPropertyChange('personFormCount');
    },
```

No changes happening on template. Array changes itself properly when action triggered. Function should take care of deleting.

Comment: In the code provided, you never actually change anything...? I mean that I can't see HOW the property changes. If you think that this line changes anything:
this.get('personFormCount').splice(index, 1);
It doesn't. It just generates a new array.

Comment: @GeorgeAcev What about now? http://dpaste.com/1585371/ Still does not work.

Comment: Splice most definitely changes the array, I think you're confusing splice with slice.

Comment: You are completely right, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` does change the array, but Ember isn't watching to see if you're splicing the array or not.  You'll really want to use the built in remove functions.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_removeObjects

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_removeObject

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_removeAt

In your case this would be a good implementation

```
{{#each personFormCount}}
      <br>Form ID: {{id}}
      <button type="submit" {{action 'removeItem' this}}>ID</button> // removes this item
      {{view 'person'}}
{{/each}}


removeItem: function(item){
      this.get('personFormCount').removeObject(item);
},
```